# Error using Standardize

Tags: list-manipulation, data, dataset

I'm trying to standardize a set of data.

```
data={{1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 
  2, 1, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 1, 
  3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
  1}, {1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 
  1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 
  2, 1}}
```

Normally i would use the function.

```
xTestStandardized = Standardize[data];
```

However I receive the error message.

Standardize::scl2: The scale function StandardDeviation evaluated to a list or zero for one or more of the columns.

Has anybody encountered this issue before?
Oddly enough if I standardize each row individually, there is no issue.

We can standardize each row using Manipulate

```
Manipulate[Standardize[data[[i]]] // N, {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: `Standardize /@ data` ?

Comment: I see, so mapping the function opposed placing "data" within square brack paranethesis resolves this.

Comment: The 3rd column is all ones: `data[[All, 3]]`. You can't standardize constant vectors because the standard deviation is 0. You'd first need to define some sort of metric of spread that doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: @Luke4737 `Standardize[data]` is different from `Standardize /@ data`. The first will standardize the columns; the 2nd will standardize the rows.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clarifying.